# rpy2 implementation with None named list is required by spsurvey::grts

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've got a shape file with a single stratum that I am applying the a-survey::grts method to. This works beautifully in R, but having a 'None' named list in rpy2 is tripping me up.

```
dsgn <- list(None=list(panel=c(Base=50), seltype="Equal"))

grts(design=dsgn,
     DesignID='newpts',
     type.frame='finite',
     src.frame='shapefile',
     in.shape=interest,
     att.frame=att,
     shapefile=TRUE,
     out.shape="newtest",
     prj=file.name)
```

The thing to note is the None named list, which is a [design requirement](https://rdrr.io/cran/spsurvey/man/grts.html) with 1 stratum. The problem comes in when I put this into rpy2, because python is, well, python.

```
dsgn = robjects.r.list(None=robjects.r.listlist(panel=c(Base=50), seltype="Equal"))
```

This nets me the syntax error: keywords can't be an expression. I understand why python is telling me this, but I can't find anywhere in the rpy2 documentation what the workaround is, nor can I find where anyone else has run into the same challenge. I've tried various forms of r.None, Null, etc, and moving entirely away from having a None stratum (which leads to errors induced by only having 1 stratum). Solutions that either create a workaround for a single stratum condition OR having a None named list in rpy2 would be super welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` is indeed a reserved word in Python, but there are few ways to work around that.

In the example below the R function `c` is:

```
c = robjects.r.c
```

**1- The general way to address this in Python is to use a `dict`**

```
dsgn = robjects.r.list(**{'None': robjects.r.listlist(panel=c(Base=50),
                                                      seltype="Equal")})
```

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/robjects_functions.html#callable

**2- The method `rcall`**

```
dsgn = robjects.r.list.rcall(
    ('None', robjects.r.listlist(panel=c(Base=50), seltype="Equal"))),
    globalenv
)
```

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/robjects_functions.html#rcall

**3- Wrapping function**

```
make_dsgn = robjects.r('function(...) {list(None=list(...))}')
dsgn = make_dsgn(panel=c(Base=50, seltype='Equal'))
```

Comment: Those worked perfectly, and I deeply appreciate the reference back to the documentation for my learning purposes! I am assuming that the 1-dict version is probably the most efficient since it is the most 'pythonic'; does that ring true in your experience?

Comment: The dict is what will work with any Python function or callable object. The two others are rpy2-specific idioms.